# React-highcharts: how do I stop the chart from re-animating when a certain prop changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

I have a chart that's built with react-highcharts that's using a `loading` state I have in redux. When `loading` is `true`, that chart is supposed to change it's `opacity` to 0.35 and back to 1 when `loading` is `false`.

My problem is that when I pass the `loading` prop into the child component, it re-renders the whole component and it makes the chart animate twice whenever `loading` changes:

```
  <SeatDemandChart
    seatVolatility={basicInputs.seatVolatility}
    desktopWidth={desktopWidth}
    spaceChartId={spaceChart}
    key={`${mobileScreenResults}_${tab}`}
    netArea={newResults.tradResults.netArea}
    seatChartResults={newResults.seatChartResults}
    measureName={measureName}
    loading={loading}
  />
```

and the component:

```
import ReactHighcharts from 'react-highcharts'

class SeatDemandChart extends Component {
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    return !isEqual(nextProps, this.props)
  }

  render() {
     const { 
       seatChartResults, 
       netArea, measureName, 
       printConfig, 
       seatVolatility, 
       spaceChartId,
       loading,
     } = this.props

     //....

     return (
       <div>
         <StyledChartContainer 
           print={printConfig && location === '/print' ? true : ''}
           loading={loading}
         >
     // ....
```

The Styled Component that's using the `loading` prop:

```
export const StyledChartContainer = styled.div`
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(39, 43, 47, 0.25);
  transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
  opacity: ${({ loading }) => loading ? 0.35 : 1};
`
```

Am I missing something? I feel like I should add more logic to `shouldComponentUpdate`, but I'm very lost on how to approach this.

Comment: What is the loading prop used for?

Comment: It's passed into `StyledChartContainer` which is using Styled components. It's what's setting the opacity. I'll update the post with that.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to use `highcharts-react-official` wrapper: https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-react-official

You will be able to use `allowChartUpdate` option, which allow you to block the chart update. Please see this live example: https://codesandbox.io/s/9j89kxvl3w

Answer (score 1):

BTW, your example doesn't actually contain the `ReactHighcharts` element.

You can use the `<ReactHighcharts isPureConfig={true}` property, which will prevent it from re-rendering unless you pass in a different `config` object. That might help, as long as you can make sure the config object is treated as immutable (e.g. don't change its inner properties and expect the chart to re-render).

Personally I've found [react-jsx-highcharts](https://github.com/whawker/react-jsx-highcharts) to be much easier to use, because of things like this.